# Rewrite rule is not working in localhost .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

The below rewrite rule is not working in localhost.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
RewriteBase http://localhost/project/

RewriteRule ^templates/assets/js/custom.js$ admin/templates/assets/js/custom.js.php [L]
```

Comment: `RewriteBase http://localhost/project/` is wrong as `RewriteBase` is for a directory not for a URL

Comment: @anubhava. Thanks for the clarification. I have tried with directory alone say using RewriteBase /project/ even then its not working.

Comment: Need more details. What URL have you tried for testing and where is this .htaccess located?